# Selection sort with array of pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I need to sort an array of float values into another array using only pointers. In this function, I've already entered all the values into the pointer array p_data_start. The code to sort is after allocating memory for the p_sort_start, I have two pointers pointing to the top of the sort array and data array. The inner for loop uses p_data to find the largest number in p_data_start, and assign it to p_data_pointer. After the inner for loop, p_data_pointer should assign it's value to the location p_sort points to. 
The value stored at the location p_data_pointer is pointing to should be zeroed out so it isn't checked again.

Here is my code:

```
/**********************************************************************/
/* Sort values of experimental scientific data into descending order  */
/**********************************************************************/
float sort_data(int p_quantity, float *p_data_start)
{
    float *p_data,             /* Pointer that moves down the data array */
             *p_sort,         /* Pointer that moves down the sort array */
             *p_sort_start,   /* Sorted array                           */
             *p_data_pointer; /* Points to the largest number           */

    /* Allocate memory for the sorted experimental scientific data   */
    if((p_sort_start = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * p_quantity)) == NULL)
    {
            printf("\nCould not allocate memory for sorted array");
            printf("\nERROR NUMBER %d OCCURED", SORTING_ERROR);
            printf("\nThe program is aborting.");
            exit(SORTING_ERROR);
    }

    /* Sort the data into descending order                           */
    for(p_sort = p_sort_start; (p_sort-p_sort_start) < p_quantity;
                                                                 p_sort++)
    {
            p_data_pointer = p_data;

            for(p_data = p_data_start; (p_data-p_data_start) < p_quantity;
                                                                    p_data++)
            {
                    if (*p_data > *p_data_pointer)
                    {
                            *p_data_pointer = *p_data;
                    }
            }

            *p_sort = *p_data_pointer;
            *p_data_pointer = 0;
    }

    /* Copy the sorted data values back into the original array     */
    memcpy(p_sort_start, p_data_start, sizeof(float) * p_quantity);

    /* Free memory from the sorted array                            */
    free(p_sort_start);

    return 0;
}
```

When I print out the data, the number are in the same order as entered, but everything else works. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `memcpy(p_data_start, p_sort_start, sizeof(float) * p_quantity);` BTW: it is **not** an array of pointers. It is a (pointer to) an array of floats. Both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
if (*p_data > *p_data_pointer)
{
    *p_data_pointer = *p_data;
}
```

What you want is indeed

```
if (*p_data > *p_data_pointer)
{
    p_data_pointer = p_data;
}
```

You just want to store the new *address* of max value into `p_data_pointer` instead of replacing the value it pointed to.